# Unity - Перемещение UI объектов мышкой

Tags: c#, unity3d, ui

Как можно реализовать перемещение объектов UI мышкой? Например в инвентаре есть 2 слота, нужно из первого переместить объект во второй слот.

Comment: Кто-то рекомендовал это видео: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pc8K_DVPgVM

Answer (score 1):

1. Сделай по невидимой панели на каждом месте
2. Найди скрипт DragAndDrop для юнити и обрабатывай через него нужную логику
3. Запоминай расположение и сами предметы через PlayerPrefs
4. Собственнно... все.